# Proof inequality with ln and arctg

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$x, y, z > 0$$
$$r=\sqrt[]{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
Proof that:
$$xy\ln{\frac{r+z}{r-z}}+xz\ln{\frac{r+y}{r-y}}+yz\ln{\frac{r+x}{r-x}} > x^2\arctan{\frac{yz}{xr}}+y^2\arctan{\frac{xz}{yr}}+x^2\arctan{\frac{xy}{zr}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $r=1$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}xy\ln\frac{1+z}{1-z}\geq\sum_{cyc}x^2\arctan\frac{yz}{x}$$ and
since $\arctan t\leq t$ for all $t>0$ and $\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}\geq t$ for all $0<t<1$, we are done!